# IE8 loading js on SSL pages

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ssl

I am having an issue where all my js files that are loaded on a ssl page break in IE 8.

Is there a technique to load them to work in all browsers and whether the page is secure or not?

Comment: IN IE 8, when I load all my jquery/js scripts, they break and do not load once on a https:// page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're directly referencing scripts on third-party sites, create local copies of the scripts on your server instead. Then in your <script> tags, use relative URLs. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/some-library.js"></script>
```

That way the browser will load them over regular HTTP if the user browses to http://yourdomain.com/, or over HTTPS if the user browses to https://yourdomain.com/.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're looking for, but you can reference links depending on the protocol by..

```
src="//domain.com/foo/bar.js"
```

To workaround any possible security warnings.